# Forward to the same JSP page I received the request from (without infinite loop)?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, java-ee-6

I have a page, `productListing.jsp` where, you guessed it, I list of products. When a client requests this page, I want the servlet it's mapped to -- `ProductsIndexController` -- to pull some data from the DB and pass it back to `productListing.jsp`.

My issue is that because (I assume) I'm forwardin the request to the same page the servlet is mapped to, it's causing infinite redirects and this error `javax.servlet.ServletException: AS-WEB-CORE-00089`

Is there a way around this? As a quick-fix for now I'm just calling the model methods straight from the JSP page, but I'd rather not do that.

**productListing.jsp (as I'd like it to be)**

```
<% 
ArrayList<Product> products = (ArrayList<Product>)request.getAttribute("products"); %>
<!-- Display data by looping over products -->
```

**ProductIndexController (servlet)**

```
@WebServlet({ "/ProductIndexController", "/productListing.jsp" })
public class ProductIndexController extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {       
        try {
            ArrayList<Product> products = Product.all();
            request.setAttribute("products", products);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Notice notice = new Notice();
            notice.addErrorMessage("Couldn't fetch products: " + e.getMessage());
            request.setAttribute("notice", notice);
        }
        request.getRequestDispatcher("/productListing.jsp").forward(request, response);
    }
```

Comment: Are you redirecting in JSP page to the servlet?

Comment: @java-devel no, the JSP is mapped to the servlet. So every time a request comes throught for the JSP page, it's mapped to the servlet.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is when you redirect, add a request parameter, say `redirected`, and set it to `redirected` in the url, then in your servlet code, just call `request.getParamemter("redirected")`, then if this request param is present, don't call redirect, otherwise, call redirect

```
if (request.getParameter("redirected") == null)
    // pay attention to the ?redirected=redirected in the url
    request.getRequestDispatcher("/productListing.jsp?redirected=redirected").forward(request, response)
```

When that request param is null, you know the request is from your jsp, not the redirected response

Comment: What are you talking about? He redirects from a different page to this servlet which in turn refirects to his productlisting jsp page, after that first redirect, we add the parameter to not cause the second redirect to loop. Explain why it never redirects

Comment: Your answer there has not thing to do with why you said it never redirects

Comment: I dont use strut to understand your other answer, but your statement previously about it never redirecting I think is noot correct

Comment: Why dont you just create a test app and run my answer above to see if it redirects?